# Fermat's little theorem application

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, alternative-proof

Prove that there exists a number of the form $\sum\limits_{n=0}^N 10^n=1111....11 $ (a sequence of $N+1$ digits 1) which is divisible by $2003$.

I found a proof of this exercise which uses the pigeonhole principle, but I would like to see if it can be proved using Fermat's little theorem, assuming that there does not exist such a number, deriving a contradiction (actually this is the way I tried).

Is it possible to prove this simply by contradiction (if Fermat's little theorem does not give a solution)?

If it is, can someone give me a hint?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is a common exercise to show that there is a number of the form $111\dots11000\dots00$ which is divisible by $k$., but there isn't always a number of the form $111\dots 11$ which is divisible by $k$.  For example, no number of the form $111\dots 11$ is divisible by $2$.  You are sure that the number must have only ones and no zeroes?

Comment: @JMoravitz $2003$ iscoprime to $10$, so one only needs ones.

Comment: but is the number 111...111.000000 is divizible by 2003 for instance the the number 111...111  is also divisible by 2003 becase 2003 does not divide a number of the form $10^n$

Comment: Since $3 \nmid 2003$, you have $2003 \mid 10^n - 1 \iff 2003 \mid \frac{10^n-1}{9}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to make things simpler, we have the following:
$$\sum_{n=0}^N 10^n=\frac{10^{N+1}-1}{9}$$
Thus, we want to find:
$$\frac{10^{N+1}-1}{9} \equiv 0 \pmod {2003}$$
Now, fractions in modular equations can be tricky, so we have to be careful here. Luckily, $9$ is coprime to $2003$ and therefore $9^{-1} \pmod {2003}$ is a thing, so get rid of the fraction:
$$(10^{N+1}-1)(9^{-1}) \equiv 0 \pmod {2003}$$
Multiply both sides by $9$ and add both sides by $1$:
$$10^{N+1} \equiv 1 \pmod {2003}$$
Now, can you try to apply Fermat's Theorem to find $N$? Good luck!

Comment: Note that  $2003$ is not  divisible by any prime $p<47$  and that $47^2>2003,$  so $2003$ is prime.

Answer (score 3):

To get started, observe that a desired $R_N:=\sum_{n=0}^N 10^n$ is divisible by $2003$ if and only if $9R_N = (10^{N+1}-1)$ is also divisible by $2003$.

This means that we require $N$ such that $10^{N+1} \equiv 1 \bmod 2003$. Apply Fermat's Little Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Using the formula for a finite geometric series, we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N 10^n = \frac{1 - 10^{N+1}}{1 - 10} = \frac{10^{N+1} -1}{9} \, .
$$
Since $p = 2003$ is prime, then $9$ is invertible mod $p$, so it suffices to find $N$ such that $10^{N+1} - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{2003}$.  By Fermat's little theorem, $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for any $a$ with $\gcd(a,p) = 1$.  Then taking $N = p-2 = 2001$ should work:
$$
10^{p-2+1} - 1 = 10^{p-1} - 1 \equiv 1 - 1 = 0 \pmod{p} \, .
$$

Comment: the prime p is 2003?

Comment: Yes, I wrote $p = 2003$ in the second sentence.